# How to fix: Required request body is missing: [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:]

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I am updating a boolean column on my database for approving customer accounts via an angular front-end button. Once I send my request, my controller throws the `Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException:Required request body is missing:` error. Have struggled debugging it and would appreciate some guidance on this.

My code so far is as follows:

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customers/afisapprove", method = 
RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> updCustAfisStatus(@RequestBody Customer 
customer) throws Exception {
    try {
        System.out.println("account no##" + 
customer.getAccountNumber());
        System.out.println("afis no##" + 
customer.getAfisStatus());
        System.out.println("afis id##" + customer.getId());

        int approveCust = 
customerService.approveAfisCustomer(customer.isActive());

        // begin saving audit trail
        auditTrail = new AuditTrail((customer.getCreatedBy()), "Approved Customer " + customer.getFullName(), date,
                "Approve Customer");
        auditTrailService.saveAuditTrail(auditTrail);
        System.out.println("approved##" + approveCust);
        if (approveCust > 0) {
            // int trash = customerService.trashAfisBio(customer.getId());
            // if(trash <= 0 ) {
            // return new ResponseEntity<>(new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV,
            // 200,false,
            // "failed to trash raw images"),HttpStatus.OK);
            // }
            return new ResponseEntity<>(
                    new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, true, "customer approved successfully"),
                    HttpStatus.OK);

        }
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, false, "failed to approve customer"), HttpStatus.OK);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(
                new CustomResponse(CustomResponse.APIV, 200, false, "Server error processing request"),
                HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Customerr")
public class Customer extends BaseModel implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="account_number")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name="teller_id")
    private String tellerId;

    @Column(name="active")
    private boolean active=false;

    @Column(name="branchId")
    private String branchId;

    @Column(name="dateOfBirth")
    private String dateOfBirth;

    @Column(name ="emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name="fullName")
    private String fullName;

    @Column(name="gender")
    private String gender;

    @Column(name="idNumber")
    private String idNumber;

    @Column(name="phoneNumber")
    private String phoneNumber;

    @Column(name="postalAddress")
    private String postalAddress;

    @Column(name="postalCode")
    private String postalCode;

    @Column(name="postalTown")
    private String postalTown;

    @Column(name="created_on",columnDefinition="datetime default getDate()")
    private Date createdOn;

    @Column(name="afisid")
    private String pbuno;

    @Column(name="userProfile",columnDefinition="varchar(max)")
    private String profilePic;

    @Column(name="verified")
    private String approved;

    @Column(name="verified_by")
    private int approvedBy;

    @Column(name="created_by", nullable = false)
    private int createdBy;

    @Column(name="verified_on")
    private Date approvedOn;

    @Column(name="afis_status")
    private String afisStatus;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private List<CustomerBio> bios;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="customer_id")
    private List<RawImages> raws;

    public Customer() {
        super();

    }

    public Customer(String accountNumber, String tellerId, boolean active, String branchId, String dateOfBirth, String emailAddress,
            String fullName, String gender, String idNumber, String phoneNumber, String postalAddress,
            String postalCode, String postalTown, Date createdOn, String pbuno, String profilePic, String approved,
            int approvedBy, Date approvedOn, List<CustomerBio> bios,String afisStatus,List<RawImages> raws,int createdBy) {
        super();
        this.tellerId = tellerId;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.active = active;
        this.branchId = branchId;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.postalAddress = postalAddress;
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
        this.postalTown = postalTown;
        this.createdOn = createdOn;
        this.pbuno = pbuno;
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
        this.approved = approved;
        this.approvedBy = approvedBy;
        this.approvedOn = approvedOn;
        this.bios = bios;
        this.afisStatus=afisStatus;
        this.raws=raws;
        this.createdBy=createdBy;
    }

    public int getCreatedBy() {
        return createdBy;
    }

    public void setCreatedBy(int createdBy) {
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }

    public String getAfisStatus() {
        return afisStatus;
    }

    public void setAfisStatus(String afisStatus) {
        this.afisStatus = afisStatus;
    }

    public String getApproved() {
        return approved;
    }

    public void setApproved(String approved) {
        this.approved = approved;
    }

    public int getApprovedBy() {
        return approvedBy;
    }

    public void setApprovedBy(int approvedBy) {
        this.approvedBy = approvedBy;
    }

    public Date getApprovedOn() {
        return approvedOn;
    }

    public void setApprovedOn(Date approvedOn) {
        this.approvedOn = approvedOn;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    public String getTellerId() {
        return tellerId;
    }

    public void setTellerRef(String tellerId) {
        this.tellerId = tellerId;
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public String getBranchId() {
        return branchId;
    }

    public void setBranchId(String branchId) {
        this.branchId = branchId;
    }

    public String getDateOfBirth() {
        return dateOfBirth;
    }

    public void setDateOfBirth(String dateOfBirth) {
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return emailAddress;
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }

    public void setGender(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getIdNumber() {
        return idNumber;
    }

    public void setIdNumber(String idNumber) {
        this.idNumber = idNumber;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getPostalAddress() {
        return postalAddress;
    }

    public void setPostalAddress(String postalAddress) {
        this.postalAddress = postalAddress;
    }

    public String getPostalCode() {
        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getPostalTown() {
        return postalTown;
    }

    public void setPostalTown(String postalTown) {
        this.postalTown = postalTown;
    }

    public Date getCreatedOn() {
        return createdOn;
    }

//    @PrePersist
    public void setCreatedOn() {
        this.createdOn = new Date();
    }

//    public List<CustomerBio> getBios() {
//        return bios;
//    }
//
//    public List<RawImages> getRaws() {
//        return raws;
//    }
//
//    public void addBio(CustomerBio bio) {
//        bio.setCustomer(this);
//        bios.add(bio);
//    }
//
//    public void addRaw(RawImages raw) {
//        raw.setCustomer(this);
//        raws.add(raw);
//    }

    public String getPbuno() {
        return pbuno;
    }

    public void setPbuno(String pbuno) {
        this.pbuno = pbuno;
    }

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 7;
    }

    public String getProfilePic() {
        return profilePic;
    }

    public void setProfilePic(String profilePic) {
        this.profilePic = profilePic;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" + "accountNumber=" + accountNumber + ", fullName=" + fullName + ", dateOfBirth=" + dateOfBirth + '}';
    }
}
```

json:

```
       {
            "Id": 13,
            "name": "KABALIISA SCOVIA",
            "afisid": "PBU433369",
            "active": false,
            "branchId": "1",
            "dateOfBirth": "2019-03-07",
            "emailAddress": "johndoe@gmail.com",
            "fullName": "Nelson",
            "gender": "Male",
            "idNumber": "90785634",
            "phoneNumber": "0721234567",
            "postalAddress": "8445",
            "postalCode": "00200",
            "postalTown": "Mombasa",
            "userProfile": "",
            "createdBy": 0
        },
```

service:

```
public int approveAfisCustomer(boolean active) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return Customerrepository.approveAfisCustomer(active);
    }
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. How i can fix it and understand the cause of the error?

Comment: Kindly check the json which is receiving from the front end, the content in the json must match the Customer class. `@RequestBody Customer customer`.   Seems the request  is not what it is expecting.

Comment: Can you provide the request details you are sending along with the structure of Customer class? If the JSON for Customer is not in the body of the HTTP Request (or not correctly formatted) you will receive this message.

Comment: @rob-scully `@RequestBody Customer customer` is my entity. I am also changing the `isActive());` flag to active on db. Or how do I modify this json?

Comment: @codeslayer yes, I understand. But the json you're providing in the request which represents customer must match the Structure of your Customer class. Can you please provide the json in the request body of the request you are sending to your service along with the contents of Customer class?

Comment: @rob-scully check above updated post with json

Comment: @codeslayer thank you, now can you post your Customer class?

Comment: @rob-scully have updated post with Customer  class

Comment: So the JSON you are using does not match the JSON in the cusotmer objec which is resulting in binding failures.

For example, take "Id": 13, in your JSON. In your customer you have tellerId which is a String. The correct way to represent and bind this in JSON would be "tellerId": "13".

The field "name" does not exist in Customer class, rather you have "fullName".

The field names in your json MUST match the field names in your Customer class. Once you resolve these the request will bind correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your posted JSON, the following attributes doesn't matched with the `@RequestBody Customer` .Change accordingly

```
  {
            "Id": 13,
            "name": "KABALIISA SCOVIA",
            "afisid": "PBU433369",

            "userProfile": "",

        },
```